# Exclude empty strings in countDistinct agg function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I exclude an empty string while using `countDistinct` aggregate function?

Input Dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(("2016", 2.1), ("", 2.1), ("2017", 1.4), (null, 1.4), (null, 0.3), (null, 0.3)).toDF("ID", "Val")
df.show(false)

+----+---+
|ID  |Val|
+----+---+
|2016|2.1|
|    |2.1|
|2017|1.4|
|null|1.4|
|null|0.3|
|null|0.3|
+----+---+
```

Below is the aggregate function I have used , which is considering empty string as a value.

```
df.groupBy("Val")
  .agg(countDistinct("ID") as "COUNT").show()
+---+-----+
|Val|COUNT|
+---+-----+
|1.4|    1|
|0.3|    0|
|2.1|    2|-----> should be counted as 1
+---+-----+
```

How can I exclude an empty string?
The expected result is:

```
+---+-----+
|Val|COUNT|
+---+-----+
|1.4|    1|
|0.3|    0|
|2.1|    1|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply condition in `agg` `function` itself like below

```
 df.groupBy("Val").agg(countDistinct(when($"ID"=!="",$"ID")) as "COUNT").show()

//output
+---+-----+                                                                     
|Val|COUNT|
+---+-----+
|1.4|    1|
|0.3|    0|
|2.1|    1|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `filter` before grouping the data to remove all empty strings:

```
df.filter($"ID" =!= "")
  .groupBy("Val")
  .agg(countDistinct("ID") as "COUNT")
```